# Generic properties of dominating/etc. reals with non-Cohen working parts

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing

The first and foremost forcing that adds a real is the Cohen forcing which approximates a new real number by giving finite approximations to its characteristics function.

But very quickly after that, we can start putting extra conditions (or side conditions if you don't mind me using that term). These are often finite families of reals from the ground model which the new real is required to respect in certain ways.

1. If the generic real is required to dominate the finite family, we get a new dominating real.
2. If the generic real is required to avoid the finite family, we get an eventually different real.
3. If the additional information is a finite subset of $\omega_1$, and the generic real is required to avoid those members of a fixed almost disjoint family indexed by the finite information, then we get a real which codes a subset of $\omega_1$.
4. If the generic real is required to be a subset of finitely many reals taken from a fixed filter, we get a pseudo-intersection to the filter.

But in all of these examples, the working part is a Cohen condition. This is often the natural choice, since it is simple and convenient to use, and the resulting forcings inherit things like being ccc from the Cohen part.

> What happens if we use a different working part?

For example, do we gain anything by using a Sacks/Laver/some other arboreal forcing for the working part? Will the new generic real inherit minimality properties, or other kind of covering/domination/bounding properties that its working part "normally have"?

---

Note: I am deliberately keeping the term "real" ambiguous here, since different interpretations make more or less sense for different examples. So the answer to "what is a real?" could be a subset of $\omega$, or a binary sequence, or just a sequence of integers, or some other reasonable interpretation of this.

Comment: My knee-jerk reaction is that arboreal forcings tend to have such additional restrictions either essentially already present (e.g. forcing with perfect subtrees of $\omega^{<\omega}$ will always yield an eventually different real) or immediately inconsistent (e.g. a perfect subtree can force the generic element of $\omega^\omega$ to be slow-growing), with Cohen conditions being sufficiently simple that there are lots of further requirements which are nontrivial yet permissible.

Comment: Sure, I only talk about what is possible anyway. You can use coinfinite conditions (Prikry-Silver) but then you can't add an eventually different real, for obvious reasons...

Comment: I'd be surprised if this isn't covered by the "trees and creatures" apparatus of Roslanowski and Shelah, so perhaps see  "Norms on Possibilities I: Forcing with trees and creatures".  This isn't an answer, but a suggestion of some place to look if you haven't already.

Comment: @Todd: Thanks. I was just curious about this, so I didn't really look anywhere. But I will take a look.

Comment: I would say that the arboreal forcings are very similar to the side-conditions forcings in that there is a finite part (the stem in the tree case), and something which governs its growth (the tree and the rules that govern strengthening of the infinite part).  So if you want to put an arboreal conditions as the working part, the essential question is: what is the relation between the part above the stem and the side conditions?

Comment: @Monroe: So you're suggesting that a tree forcing is itself a Cohen+side kind of situation, in the sense that you have a finite stem, but now an infinite family of conditions?

Comment: Yes, something like that. What if the side conditions put some restrains on the trees? So you have two levels of guidance.

Comment: @Monroe: And in a nutshell, that's my question.

Comment: I have some good news and I have some bad news. The good news is that Shelah's paper Sh707 addresses your question (see the discussion of trunk controllers in Section 1). The bad news is that it's probably way more general than what you expected.

Comment: @Haim: Thanks. I'll look at this.